# Return error msg in payload when header not present

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have this action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetModifiedSince([HeaderCompanyId] Guid? xCompanyId)
{
...
}
```

The `HeaderCompanyId` class in the above action method is defined here:

```
public class HeaderCompanyIdAttribute : FromHeaderAttribute
{
    public HeaderCompanyIdAttribute()
    {
        Name = "x-company-id";
    }
}
```

I'm using this `IOperationFilter` to make the `xCompanyId` required:

```
public class AddSwaggerToStandardHeadersFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var companyIdHeader = operation.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "x-company-id");
        if (companyIdHeader != null)
        {
            companyIdHeader.Description = "Company id";
            companyIdHeader.Required = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I add the `OperationFilter`:

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterSwagger(this IServiceCollection services) =>
    services.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction =>
    {
        ...
        setupAction.OperationFilter<AddSwaggerToStandardHeadersFilter>();
    }
}
```

I can see the header marked as mandatory in the Swagger UI.
But when I hit the endpoint with no value for the `xCompanyId` the `ModelState.IsValid = true` and I get no error msg back about the header being required.

**How can I return a 4XX to indicate that the `xCompanyId` header is needed?**
Ideally if I put a breakpoint in the action method, it shouldn't even get hit.

Comment: Is this xCompanyId required in all your request or just some action in your application?

Comment: It's required in all requests.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner did find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can try to use a Model instead of 'Guid' parameter

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetModifiedSince([FromHeader]YourCustomHeader headers)
{
 ...
}
```

use your custom model

```
public class YourCustomHeader
{
    [Required]
    public string xCompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing a simple check in the API method:

```
 if (xCompanyId == null)
  return BadRequest("CompanyId is mandatory");
```

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it DRY because it's required in all action methods. I thought there might be some Attribute I could use.

Comment: Similar to the [Required] attribute for model properties.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner okay, see my next example with a model

Answer (score 0):

You can add your validation in the request pipe line as below in Startup.cs Config part.

```
app.Use(async(context,next)=>{
                var companyHeader=context.Request.Headers["xCompanyId"];
                if(companyHeader==null)
                {
                  context.Response.StatusCode=400;//Bad request if no companyHeader
                  await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
                }
                else{
                await next.Invoke();}
            });
```